# Linux Mint (Ubuntu) Microsoft Access Replacement?

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, linux-mint, database

I've just switched over from Window to Linux Mint, and the only thing I'm missing is a replacement for Microsoft Access.

I'm aware of LibreOffice (which comes installed), are there any others I should look at?
Any better? or any that can import an accdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with QT and SQLite.

SQLite is very simple database. All data are in single file. The QT is a toolkit for creating application in C++. There is a nice IDE (for creating GUI) too, QTCreator. The combination could be an overkill for small projects, though.

It should be in official repository.

As of importing MS Access files. It is very hard. Even Microsoft has problems with converting old version of database files to newer formats.

Comment: I know nothing, nothing! about making an application. I would just need mainly the table view that Access has and I could always export the Access Table to whatever, I guess?

Comment: If You need something simple, try looking for "SQLite GUI". I used to use this one http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/index.html

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044/good-free-alternative-to-ms-access

The short answer is that in terms of UI, form creation, compatibility with .accdb, etc. there isn't really anything solid that's comparable to MS Access in the Linux world.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [Kexi](http://www.kexi-project.org/). Kexi is an open source visual database applications creator, a long-awaited competitor for programs like MS Access or Filemaker.

[image]
<sup>**Importing Northwind sample Microsoft Access (.mdb) database using Kexi on Linux**</sup>

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really provide more information than the OP would get in a Google search.  At least describe what makes the product a good solution. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.